# How to move many tables from one schema into another schema in PostgreSQL automatically?

Tags: postgresql, schema

I want to move all tables from one schema into another schema.
I do not want to do it manually. How can I do it automatically. Both schemas are in one database.

Comment: Does the target schema already contain tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) you can set a new schema `new_schema` of a given table `my_table` with:

```
alter table my_table set schema new_schema;
```

To set schema of all tables in a schema (`old_schema` here) you should use [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) in a plpgsql block:

```
do $$
declare 
    rec record;
begin
    for rec in
        select relname
        from pg_class
        where relkind = 'r'
        and relnamespace = 'old_schema'::regnamespace
        -- and relname ilike '%' -- you can filter table names here
    loop
        execute format(
            'alter table old_schema.%I set schema new_schema',
            rec.relname);
    end loop;
end; $$
```

Read also about `pg_class` in [the docs.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/catalog-pg-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution before @klin writes his answer. I share that solution with  you:

```
DO
$$DECLARE
   my_table record;
BEGIN
  
   FOR my_table IN
      SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='my_schema'

   LOOP
      EXECUTE format(' CREATE TABLE my_target_schema.%s AS ( SELECT *  FROM  my_schema.%s) ',     my_table.table_name,my_table.table_name);
   END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

It worked for me. n fact, this solution just copies the tables in the target schema but still you should delete them from the first schema if thats what you want.